# troubleshooting Windows XP and smb

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, smb

I have problem with mapping smb network shares to windows XP (net use and Windows Explorer). In LAN I have two Windows XP computers. One of them (let's name it XP_1) can map share without problems. The second (let's name it XP_2) - can't.
The smb Linux server (Icy Box NAS 4220) host name is `storage1`. XP_2 can ping it by name, but

`net view \\storage1`

gives
`System error 53 has occurred.`

and `net view \\IPAddress` fails in the same way.

[Troubleshooting guide from MS help](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_pingconnect.mspx?mfr=true) said that "the remote computer might not be running the File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks service." But it is not true. I can connect to this share from another computer in the same network.

`ipconfig /all` showed  `Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed`

I changed it to `Broadcast` with no success.

The firewall is disabled.

What should I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Are both XP machines running the same versions and patch level? Do both XP machines have the same usernames?

Comment: Path levels and versions are the same. But probably OS configuration differs. And I have to use different username from local OS user name. This username is defined on smb server.